# crop landmarks part of the face using Google vision API

Tags: java, android, google-vision

I am trying to crop out the face from an image using google vision api. I understood how to get the landmarks from their sample code. But I don't know how to crop the face using those landmarks. Can someone provide some pseudo code or guide me on how to proceed further thanks.

Comment: Which mimetype are you working with? Jpeg, PNG, GIF, etc. ? Did you look into Image processing libraries such as Imagemagick, opencv? Java also provides BufferedImage which may have support for crop. But to support images such as CMYK or Gif etc., you will have to use ImageMagick/twelvemonkeys, etc. Please provide more information. Also, there are enough resources online on doing such simple tasks. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates using the cloud vision client to retrieve the vertices of faces in an image (assume the following file is called `faces.py`):

```
import io
import sys

from google.cloud import vision

vision_client = vision.Client()
with io.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()
image = vision_client.image(content=content)

faces = image.detect_faces()
print('Faces:')
for face in faces:
    bounds = ''
    for bound in face.bounds.vertices:
        bounds += ('{' + str(getattr(bound, 'x_coordinate', 0)) + ',' +
                   str(getattr(bound, 'y_coordinate', 0)) + '}')
    print('face bounds: {}'.format(bounds))
```

Your `requirements.txt` would look something like:

```
google-cloud-vision==0.22.0
```

You would run the app as:

```
virutalenv env && source env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
python faces.py image.jpg
```

Output is:

```
face bounds: {105,460}{516,460}{516,938}{105,938}
```

Those would be where you would clip to to highlight the face which is [covered in depth elsewhere](http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0202/).